# How do I get a HANDLE to the containing directory from a file HANDLE?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, file-io

Given a HANDLE to a file (e.g. `C:\\FolderA\\file.txt`), I want a function which will return a HANDLE to the containing directory (in the previous example, it would be a HANDLE to `C:\\FolderA`). For example:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(
                  "C:\\FolderA\\file.txt",
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                  NULL);
HANDLE hDirectory = somefunc(hFile);
```

Possible implementation for `someFunc`:

```
HANDLE someFunc(HANDLE h)
{
    char *path = getPath(h);             // "C:\\FolderA\\file.txt"
    char *parent = getParentPath(path);  // "C:\\FolderA"
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(
              parent,
              GENERIC_READ,
              FILE_SHARE_READ,
              NULL,
              OPEN_EXISTING,
              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
              NULL);
    free(parent);
    free(path);
    return hFile;
}
```

But is there a way to implement `someFunc` without `getParentPath` or without making it look at the string and removing everything after the last directory separator (because this is terrible from a performance point of view)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the *real* problem you try to solve?

Comment: And please don't tag both C and C++, pick the *one* language you want a solution in.

Comment: Id be fine with a solution in either language which is why I tagged both. As for the reason, the main one is performance: getting the file path from a HANDLE is slow, compounded by a lot of unnecessary memory allocation / deallocation when the OS should know what the containing directory is without needing to resort to paths.

Comment: I haven't fully understood what you're trying to do. So maybe FindFirstFile and FindNextFile are the functions you should take a look at.

Comment: @user743414 that is looking at the children, not the parent. Given a HANDLE to `C:\\FolderA\\file.txt` I want a function which will return a HANDLE to `C:\\FolderA`

Comment: I don't really see a need for multiple memory allocations in the most common use-cases... For a normal path (as the ones you show examples of) its length can be at most `MAX_PATH` characters. You could have an array of that size and use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea) to get the path name. Then truncate the string at the last back-slash (use e.g. `strrchr` to find it, and replace it by `'\0'`) and you have the path to the parent directory.

Comment: What are you planning to to with the _handle_ to the directory? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You have to get the path, you dont already have it. That will cause a lot of allocations.

Comment: _"this is terrible from a performance point of view"_: what makes you think this has an impact on performance?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have measured that this is slow and am looking for a faster way. can you please stop questioning my motives and either answer the question or let someone else do so.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, going forward we should not assume classic DOS paths (i.e. paths without "\\?\") are limited to `MAX_PATH` characters. New software should be developed as long-path aware (and flagged as such in the application manifest) in order to support Windows 10 systems that have long-paths enabled in the registry.

Comment: Your conclusions are wrong. Memory allocation is not the botlleneck. Having said that, insisting on using the ANSI API results in many spurious allocations. And denies you access to objects named outside the ANSI character set. Use the Unicode API.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what `getParentPath` is. I assume it's a function that searches for the trailing backslash in the string and uses that to strip off the file specification. You don't have to define such a function yourself; Windows already provides one for you—[`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchremovefilespec). (Note that this assumes the specified path actually contains a file name to remove. If the path doesn't contain a file name, it will remove the trailing directory name. There are other functions you can use to verify whether a path contains a file specification.)

The older version of this function is [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathremovefilespecw), which is what you would use on downlevel operating systems where the newer, safer function is not available.

Outside of the Windows API, there are other ways of doing the same thing. If you're targeting C++17, there is the `filesystem::path` class. Boost provides something similar. Or you could write it yourself with the `find_last_of` member function of the `std::string` class, if you absolutely have to. (But prefer not to re-invent the wheel. There are lots of edge cases when it comes to path manipulation that you probably won't think of, and that your testing probably won't reveal.)

You express concerns about the performance of this approach. This is nonsense. **Stripping some characters from a string is not a slow operation.** It wouldn't even be slow if you started searching from the beginning of the string and then, once you found the file specification, made a second copy of the string, again starting from the beginning of the string. It's a simple loop searching through the characters of a reasonable-length string, and then a simple `memcpy`. **There is absolutely no way that this operation could be a performance bottleneck in code that does file I/O.**

But, the implementation probably isn't even going to be that naïve. You can optimize it by starting the search from the *end* of the path string, reducing the number of characters that you have to iterate through, and you can avoid any type of memory copy altogether if you're allowed to manipulate the original string. With a C-style string, you just replace the trailing path separator (the one that demarcates the beginning of the path specification) with a NUL character (`\0`). With a C++-style string, you just call the `erase` member function.

In fact, if you *really* care about performance, this is virtually *guaranteed* to be faster than making a system call to retrieve the containing folder from a file object. **System calls are a lot slower than some compiler-generated, inlinable code to iterate through a string and strip out a sub-string.**

**Once you have the path to the directory, you can obtain a `HANDLE` to it by calling the [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function with the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag.** (It is necessary to pass that flag if you want to retrieve a handle to a directory.

---

> I have measured that this is slow and am looking for a faster way.

Your measurements are wrong. Either you've made the common mistake of benchmarking a debugging build, where the standard library functionality (e.g., `std::string`) is not optimized, and/or the real performance bottleneck is the file I/O. `CreateFile` is *not* a speedy function by any stretch of the imagination. I can almost guarantee that is going to be your hotspot.

---

**Note that if you don't already have the path, it is straightforward to obtain the path from a `HANDLE` to a file.** As was pointed out in the comments, on Windows Vista and later, you simply need to call the [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) function. More details are available in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/obtaining-a-file-name-from-a-file-handle) on MSDN, including sample code and an alternative for use on downlevel versions of Windows.

As was mentioned already in the comments to the question, you can optimize this further by allocating a buffer of length `MAX_PATH` (or perhaps even larger) on the stack. That compiles to a single instruction to adjust the stack pointer, so it won't be a performance bottleneck, either. (Okay, I lied: you actually will need *two* instructions—one to create space on the stack, and the other to free the allocated space on the stack. Still not a performance problem.) That way, you don't even have to do any dynamic memory allocation.

Note that for maximum robustness, especially on Windows 10, you want to handle the case that a path is longer than `MAX_PATH`. In such cases, your stack-allocated buffer will be too small, and the function you call to fill it will return an error. Handle that error, and allocate a larger buffer on the free store. That will be slower, but this is an edge case and probably not one that is worth optimizing. The 99% common case will use the stack-allocated buffer.

Furthermore, eryksun points out (in comments to this answer) that, although it is convenient, `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` requires multiple system calls to map the file object between the NT and DOS namespaces and to normalize the path. I haven't disassembled this function, so I can't confirm his claims, but I have no reason to doubt them. Under normal circumstances, you wouldn't worry about this sort of overhead or possible performance costs, but since this seems to be a big concern for your application, you can use eryksun's alternative suggestion of calling [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex) and requesting the `FileNameInfo` class. `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` is a general, multi-purpose function that can retrieve all different sorts of information about a file, including the path. Its implementation is simpler, calling directly down to the native [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) function. I would have thought `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` was just a user-mode wrapper providing exactly this service, but eryksun's research suggests it is doing extra work that you might want to avoid if this is truly a performance hot-spot. I have to qualify this slightly by noting that `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, in order to retrieve the `FileNameInfo`, is going to have to create an I/O Request Packet (IRP) and call down to the underlying device driver. That's not a cheap operation, so I'm not sure that the additional overhead of normalizing the path is really going to matter. But in this case, there's no real harm in using the `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` approach, since it's a documented function.

---

If you've written the code as described but are still having measurable performance problems, then please post that code for someone to review and help you optimize. The [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site is a great place to get help like that on working code. Feel free to leave me a link to such a question in a comment under this answer so that I don't miss it.

**Whatever you do, *please* stop calling the ANSI versions of the Windows API functions (the ones that end with an `A` suffix).** You want the wide-character (Unicode) versions. These end with a `W` suffix, and work with strings composed of `WCHAR` (== `wchar_t`) characters. Aside from the fact that the ANSI versions have been deprecated for decades now because they do not provide Unicode support (it is not optional for any application written after the year 2000 to support Unicode characters in paths), as much as you care about performance, you should be aware of the fact that all `A`-suffixed API functions are just stubs that convert the passed-in ANSI string to a Unicode string and then delegate to the `W`-suffixed version. If the function *returns* a string, a second conversion also must be done by the `A`-suffixed version, since all native APIs work with Unicode strings. Performance isn't the real reason why you should avoid calling ANSI functions, but perhaps it's one that you'll find more convincing.

There *might* be a way to do what you want (map a file object via a `HANDLE` to its containing directory), but it would require undocumented usage of the NT native API. I don't see anything at all in the documented functions that would allow you to obtain this information. It certainly isn't accessible via the `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` function. For better or worse, the user-mode file system API is almost *entirely* path-based. Presumably, it *is* tracked internally, but even the documented NT native API functions that take a root directory `HANDLE` (e.g., `NtDeleteFile` via the `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` structure) allow this field to be NULL, in which case the full path string is used.

As always, if you had provided more details on the bigger picture, we could probably provide a more appropriate solution. This is what the commenters were driving at when they mentioned an XY problem. Yes, people are questioning your motives because that's how we provide the most appropriate help.

Comment: Assuming we don't already have the file path, I'd start with a stack buffer of 1024 characters instead of `MAX_PATH`. This is a reasonable size that should handle almost all cases. `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` requires multiple system calls to resolve the device from NT back to DOS and normalize a path. I wouldn't use it. For this case, I'd use `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`: `FileNameInfo`, which requires only one `NtQueryInformationFile` system call.

Comment: As to using a `RootDirectory` handle in NT, the Windows file API uses this only for opens relative to the working directory, e.g. "spam.txt" or "./eggs/spam.txt". (In contrast, the registry API uses it always.) Note that NT doesn't support "." and  ".." components (except for faked entries in directory listings), so a relative path with ".." like "../spam.txt" has to first be resolved to the full path before making a system call (e.g. `NtCreateFile`). Thus Windows stores *both* a handle for and the path of the working directory in the PEB process parameters.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your comments. I was not aware that `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` was doing extra work; I assumed it was a simple user-mode wrapper doing exactly what you suggested as the alternative. I've updated the answer to reflect that performance concern and your alternative suggestion. Regarding your second comment, I am fully aware of that. I don't see how that has any relevance in mapping a file HANDLE to its parent directory. As you said, the PEB contains a HANDLE to the working directory. The question is, does a native I/O subsystem file object contain a reference to its directory?

Comment: A filesystem [file object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) doesn't have a pointer to a file object for the containing directory. That would entail creating kernel file objects back up to the root directory every time a filesystem file is created or opened. On a related note, but not what the OP wants, the file object does reference the mounted filesystem device via the volume parameter block (VPB). So it can be used to open a file by ID via `OpenFileById` on a supported filesystem such as NTFS.

Comment: Regarding `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` with the default flags, first it calls `NtQueryObject` to get the device name, but that includes the filesystem path (filename), so it calls `NtQueryInformationFile` to split out the opened filename. Then it calls `NtCreateFile` to open the mountpoint manager and `NtDeviceIoControlFile` to query the DOS name of the target device. Then it calls `NtQueryInformationFile` a second time to query the normalized filename. If it's a UNC path ("\Device\Mup"), normalizing requires `GetLongPathNameW`, which calls `NtQueryDirectoryFile` on short path components.

Comment: `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` with the flags `VOLUME_NAME_NONE | FILE_NAME_OPENED` should be implemented as a single `NtQueryInformationFile` system call, like `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`: `FileNameInfo`.

Comment: Regarding ANSI vs Unicode, I agree with the caveat that in Windows 10 there's a setting to use UTF-8 (65001) for the system ANSI and OEM codepages. I'm uncertain about Microsoft's plans for the ANSI API. Using it with UTF-8 may be supported indefinitely. That will be convenient for cross-platform applications and environments that previously have had to implement their own UTF-8 <=> UTF-16LE wrappers.

Comment: @ErykSun You wrote "`GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` with the flags `VOLUME_NAME_NONE | FILE_NAME_OPENED` ***should*** be implemented as a single `NtQueryInformationFile` system call..."  but "should" is a bit ambiguous here and I can't figure out what you mean. Are you saying that internally that's what the API does in fact do (as far as you know), or that you know that it was implemented wrong internally in a way that can't be worked-around?

Comment: @GlennSlayden, for some reason it still calls `NtQueryObject`: `ObjectNameInformation`, though AFAICT it doesn't need to. The I/O manager has this call hooked via the `QueryNameProcedure` of the File object type, and it implements it by concatenating the NT device name with the path from querying the `FileNameInformation` from the file system. This is redundant because `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` has to call `NtQueryInformationFile`: `FileNameInformation` anyway. Then it also goes on to needlessly split out the device path from the former call, but this is discarded for `VOLUME_NAME_NONE`.

Comment: @ErykSun Might have figured out your answer. Although both `GetFi…tionByHandleEx / FILE_NAME_INFO` and `GetFi…ameByHandleW / VOLUME_NAME_NONE` don't include the final volume name in the result, the returned path is always *rooted for the final volume*. This can be a different volume than the volume of the queried handle, if the original `CreateFileW` path traverses cross-volume junctions. I assume the volume activity you're seeing is for supporting the analysis of such volume-switching cases, and thus required for correctness regardless of whether prepending the volume name is requested.

Comment: @ErykSun ...To test this hypothesis, try adding `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` when creating the file handle with `CreateFileW` (You'll also need `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`, if you don't already have it, which, in turn, might need a `0` for `FILE_ACCESS` to assuage security). Anyway, what `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` does is put the brakes on any volume traversal, shunting the "final" path towards the ***root of the junction's own volume*** (as opposed to following on to its target). I think this will exclude the possibility of leaving the volume, so maybe the busywork will go away?

Comment: @GlennSlayden, `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`: `FileNameInfo` is just a simple wrapper around `NtQueryInformationFile`: `FileNameInformation`. OTOH, `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` does much more by default. It gets the normalized name on the volume and maps the native device path to a DOS path using the mount-point manager database, or, in the case of remote paths, by manually mapping "\Device\Mup" to the UNC device junction "\\?\UNC".

Comment: @GlennSlayden, as to reparse points -- e.g. symlinks (like Unix symlinks, relative and absolute) and mount points (i.e. file-system junctions, which are exactly like Unix mount points and bind mounts in how they get traversed by relative symlinks) -- we're getting the final path after any and all reparsing is done. `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` will open a reparse point if it's the final component, but it doesn't prevent traversing directory symlinks and file-system junctions, or Object Manager junctions (e.g. regular DOS drives like "C:", mapped drives and subst drives), in path parsing.